# jquery selecting all the children classes with conditional

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to find all the `.post-comment-replies` that have `'.post-comment-reply'` nested in them (not first level).

With the code below I also get those `.post-comment-replies` that have no `.post-comment-reply` nested in them.

```
$(document).on('click', '.open-all-post-comments', function (event) {
  var post_id = $(this).data('pid');
  var all_replies = $('#post_' + post_id).find('.post-comment-replies');
  all_replies.show();
  $(this).closest('.open-all-post-comments-row').hide();
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by _"(not first level)"_ ?

Comment: I meant that it's deep nested, so something like `.children()` wouldn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with [`:has()`](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) selector,

```
var all_replies = $('#post_' + post_id)
                   .find('.post-comment-replies:has(.post-comment-reply)');
```

The `:has()` selector here will assist us to get the `.post-comment-replies` which has one or more descendant `.post-comment-reply`.

And if you want to make the immediate child to escape from the selector, then you can use,

```
var all_replies = $('#post_' + post_id)
                   .find('.post-comment-replies > :has(.post-comment-reply)');
```

Comment: See OP at _"(not first level)."_

Comment: Though not certain if OP is referencing `.post-comment-replies` or `.post-comment-reply` ?

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Will mark right once I can.

Comment: @SzilardMagyar Glad to help!

Comment: @guest271314 Also addressed the issue that you mentioned. But I believe OP is not seeking for that. :)